# Node.js express login cookie and URL

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, server

I am quite new to Node.js and I have two problems I cannot seem to be able to solve nor find any solutions on the internet.

1. If I want to create a login function (I have everything setup already except the cookies part) I have to somehow get the servers response, set a cookie and send it (express).

Now I'm wondering how should I get into this to use the variable in the login function?

The login function accepts `callback, request, response` as parameters. I wanted to return a callback whether the cookie is set after setting it. But the problem occurs when I want to set the cookie. I have to use `response.send()` which results in an infinite loop.

2. Is it possible to visit for example ***localhost/mywebsite*** and still get the server to work instead of
   **localhost:8080**? (8080 is port I'm listening to, as an example)

Comment: To answer #2 the ports are required for the URL

Comment: #2 would be possible using apache or nginx (or another webserver that understands proxys) as proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local) is a wonderful guide on setting up authentication in Express using a tried-and-true authentication library called [Passport](http://www.passportjs.org). And [here](https://auth0.com/blog/building-and-authenticating-nodejs-apps/) is a second guide using an enterprise-grade (there's a free version) library from [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) and it has a lot more features regarding identity.

**Update**
So once the user logs in, you could send a cookie like this: `res.cookie(cookieObject).send(responseObject)` - more on this [here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie). It would then be the browser/client-side framework's responsibility to return the cookie with every request. You could use the [cookieparser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser) package from NPM to help parse cookies from the `req` object. Let us know if this helps.

Comment: I am still wondering how should i store the response variable to use across my framework.

Thank you